# How change word orientation with php in html?

Tags: php, html, cpu-word

I have create a word document to use this method

```
  <?php
        $word= "";
        $word  .= "<h2 style='font-family: Arial;'>My title</h2>";
        $cleanContent = utf8_decode($word);
    file_put_contents("mynewworddocument.doc",$cleanContent,LOCK_EX);
   ?>
```

I have 2 questions.

1.- With this process it's possible to change the orientation page(landscape or portrait)?

2.- It's possible to create a page break? If yes, how?

Thank's

Comment: Technically this is not even a valid Word document. Its possible Word can detect this as html and display it, but unless you generate a real word file, you wont be able to control other aspects of Word format settings.

Comment: You realise that you're not actually creating a Word document, simply a file with an extension of .doc that contains html markup

Comment: This has absolutely NOTHING to do with PHP. This is a CSS issue, since all you're doing is using HTML to **FORGE** a word file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters have already mentioned, you are not creating a real word document. This is also not as easy as you might think. But for your luck, there are cracks out there that solve such problems. For example PHPWord: http://phpword.codeplex.com/ | https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/

If you really want to create a .doc word document, try to use that library.

Comment: Please note that PHPWord is now hosted on github: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/

Comment: Thank's, you have answer my question. It's not possible and obligatory to passt with a library.